# git-check-ignore lists files which aren't actually ignored when created in the working tree

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario, where I want to ignore everything except `foo.txt` in a newly created git repository.

```sh
$ git init
$ git check-ignore foo.txt bar.txt
# no output, both files are not ignored

$ echo -e "*\n!foo.txt" > .gitignore
$ git check-ignore foo.txt bar.txt
# output:
# foo.txt
# bar.txt
```

So the pattern did not work, as both files would be ignored by git. But is that really the case?

```sh
$ touch {foo,bar}.txt
$ git status
# output:
# Untracked files:
# foo.txt
```

So the pattern **does** work. But why does `git-check-ignore` output the file in the first invocation? Is there any way for `git-check-ignore` to respect the pattern as expected?

Tested with git v2.19 and v2.20 on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `git check-ignore` is intended not to tell you which files are or would be *ignored*, but rather to help you debug a `.gitignore` file by showing you which names match some pattern (note that `.gitignore` lists only the last applicable match).  As such, used without `-v`, it's pretty misleading.  Used *with* `-v`:

```
$ git check-ignore -v foo.txt bar.txt
.gitignore:2:!foo.txt   foo.txt
.gitignore:1:*  bar.txt
```

it tells you that `foo.txt` matches line 2, which is a "do not ignore" directive.

Without `-v`, all you see is that both names match some line.  When the line begins with `!`, it would be helpful if Git said so even without `-v`.  That seems like a defect in the command.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! so is there a way to mimic the desired behavior (i.e. checking if files would actually be ignored according to `.gitignore`) with this or another git command?

Comment: Not really, no - the best I can come up with is `git check-ignore -v` and look for whether the result says `!` or not. You must also inspect the index itself (`git ls-files --stage` or similar) to see if the file is currently in the index, in which case anything in `.gitignore` or an exclude file has no effect on it.